# problem in reloading tableview

Tags: iphone

HI all

i am using

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [tableview reloadData];////not working
}
```

but my table is not reloading.but when i put 
[tableview reloadData];
in viewdidload, my data didnt show up.

BUt on rerunning the app, whole data shown up...
i m confused ,what is happeneing here.plz suggest me a proper way to reload table.

Comment: does the table go blank or does new data simply not appear? I suspect there's a problem in a different method.

Comment: whole table get blanked. but when i rerun my app, whole data comes up.

Comment: are you getting data from internet like xml parsing..?

Comment: no no, i am using sqlite to insert data from one view, and just displaying it in another view's table view.after inserting data when i move to this tablewvieww(wher i am reloading my table), nothing comes up, but when i rerun my apps, data is filled in table view.

Comment: i think its problm in method calling..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

check that you have set the delegates properly

In

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [datas count];
  }
```

Make sure that you update the mutable array "datas" with the values.Because only with reference to this array count table cells are created.

All the best.

Comment: that count is returning value...table has values.but on he same instance it doesnt get loaded, but when i close my app and rerun again...data comes up. its kind of strange...no ida wat is goin wrong here